# how can i fix simpleUMLCE is incompatible in Android Studio

Tags: android

I installed the simpleUMLCE plugin for code analysis.

But I keep getting this error `Plugin "simpleUMLCE" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).`. And simpleUMLCE doesn't work.

The simpleUMLCE tab does not appear on the left, and it is not installed even if look at File> Settings> Plugin.

There is no problem using Android Studio, but I hope this error does not come out.

How can i fix?

Comment: Is this issue solved yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, the default plugins folder is:
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`
You will find simpleUMLCE jar file in this folder.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! This is my solution! :D

Comment: Thanks!  Thanks!  Thanks!

Comment: I have found the file in this path. What to do next?

Answer (score 1):

MAC:
Go to /Users/Pro/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins and delete the simpleUMLCE jar file.

WINDOWS:
Go to your Android plugins files and delete the simpleUMLCE jar file.

And restart your IDE ! It's works !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but simpleUMLCE folder doesn't exist in my Android's plugins folder.

Comment: it's a jar file not a folder, you can looking for simpleUMLCE jar files and remove them

Comment: I couldn't find it because I only looked at the Android studio folder. Thanks for helping me solve this. :)